# Can I insert an hyperlink into a non empty cell of a Google Spreadsheets documents?

Tags: google-sheets

my problem is that if I add something like this in an empty cell of a Google Spreadsheets documents it work great

```
=HYPERLINK("www.google.co.uk"; "Google")
```

But If I add this link to a non empty cell it don't work.

For example if the content of my cell is something like to:

```
Linkt to interesting post: =HYPERLINK("www.google.co.uk"; "Google")
```

I can't see the hyperlink. Why? Can I do this thing in some way?

Tnx

Andrea

Comment: Is there some reason you need two different strings to display? Why not just change the "Google" to "Check out interesting article on Google" inside the HYPERLINK function?

Answer (score 2):

In order to combine text and formulas, the text must be wrapped in quotes, and concatenated to the link:

```
="Link to interesting post: " & HYPERLINK("http://www.google.com"; "Google")
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to work for me. It also doesn't work if I replace the ; with a , (semicolon with a comma). I wouldn't be surprised if there's no way to do this though.

Comment: Oh, I see. The link is not displayed as a link, the link text is simply output without any underlining/blue color. This might seem like a bug. I have reported it via the "Report a problem" menu item in Google spreadsheets.